# How to get Top 5 and Lowest 5 values in an object of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Given an object that looks like this:

```
let abilities =  {
      "technical": {
        "Corners": 12,
        "Crossing": 12,
        "Dribbling": 20,
        "Finishing": 14,
        "First Touch": 17,
        "Free Kick": 13,
        "Heading": 7,
        "Long Shots": 11,
        "Long Throws": 5,
        "Marking": 3,
        "Passing": 15,
        "Penalty Taking": 19,
        "Tackling": 4,
        "Technique": 18
      },
      "mental": {
        "Aggression": 8,
        "Anticipation": 12,
        "Bravery": 17,
        "Composure": 15,
        "Concentration": 13,
        "Decisions": 16,
        "Determination": 15,
        "Flair": 18,
        "Leadership": 6,
        "Off The Ball": 14,
        "Positioning": 7,
        "Teamwork": 9,
        "Vision": 16,
        "Work Rate": 12
      },
      "physical": {
        "Acceleration": 17,
        "Agility": 20,
        "Balance": 16,
        "Jumping Reach": 8,
        "Natural Fitness": 16,
        "Pace": 16,
        "Stamina": 17,
        "Strength": 11
      }
    }
```

I want to get the keys and values of the 5 highest and 5 lowest values.

I first tried to get the top integer value in each object inside the `abilities` object by doing:

```
Object.keys(abilities).forEach(key => {
  let value = abilities[key];
  console.log(key)
  console.log(value)
  let maxval = Object.keys(abilities).reduce((a, b) => abilities[a] > abilities[b] ? a : b);
  console.log(maxval)
});
```

This prints out the name of the inner objects and the entire sub-object itself.

```
> technical
> {Corners: 12, Crossing: 12, Dribbling: 20, Finishing: 14, First Touch: 17, ...}
```

However, the `maxval` doesn't give anything related to the Max.

How may I solve my task?

Comment: What exactly is the expected output, do you want an array or object or something for both the mins and maxes for each outer key (like `technical` and `mental`)?

Comment: Given the object like that, I am expecting something like: `top = {"Dribbling": 20, "Agility": 20, "Penalty Taking": 19, "Technique": 18, "Flair": 18}` and 'low = {"Marking": 3, "Tackling": 4, "Long Throws": 5, "Leadership": 6, "Heading": 7}` Separating into two functions is also fine. It's the top 5 and lowest 5 abilities among all objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want the five highest values and five lowest values, extract the values and `sort` in descending order, extracting the highest and lowest five values.

```js
let abilities = {"technical":{"Corners":12,"Crossing":12,"Dribbling":20,"Finishing":14,"First Touch":17,"Free Kick":13,"Heading":7,"Long Shots":11,"Long Throws":5,"Marking":3,"Passing":15,"Penalty Taking":19,"Tackling":4,"Technique":18},"mental":{"Aggression":8,"Anticipation":12,"Bravery":17,"Composure":15,"Concentration":13,"Decisions":16,"Determination":15,"Flair":18,"Leadership":6,"Off The Ball":14,"Positioning":7,"Teamwork":9,"Vision":16,"Work Rate":12},"physical":{"Acceleration":17,"Agility":20,"Balance":16,"Jumping Reach":8,"Natural Fitness":16,"Pace":16,"Stamina":17,"Strength":11}};

const sortedValues = Object.values(abilities).flatMap(Object.entries).sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a);

const fiveHighest = sortedValues.slice(0, 5);
const fiveLowest = sortedValues.slice(-5);

console.log(fiveHighest);
console.log(fiveLowest);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

You can also make the two-dimensional arrays into objects using `reduce`:

```js
let abilities = {"technical":{"Corners":12,"Crossing":12,"Dribbling":20,"Finishing":14,"First Touch":17,"Free Kick":13,"Heading":7,"Long Shots":11,"Long Throws":5,"Marking":3,"Passing":15,"Penalty Taking":19,"Tackling":4,"Technique":18},"mental":{"Aggression":8,"Anticipation":12,"Bravery":17,"Composure":15,"Concentration":13,"Decisions":16,"Determination":15,"Flair":18,"Leadership":6,"Off The Ball":14,"Positioning":7,"Teamwork":9,"Vision":16,"Work Rate":12},"physical":{"Acceleration":17,"Agility":20,"Balance":16,"Jumping Reach":8,"Natural Fitness":16,"Pace":16,"Stamina":17,"Strength":11}};

const sortedValues = Object.values(abilities).flatMap(Object.entries).sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a);

const fiveHighest = sortedValues.slice(0, 5).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({ ...a, [k]: v }), {});
const fiveLowest = sortedValues.slice(-5).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({ ...a, [k]: v }), {});

console.log(fiveHighest);
console.log(fiveLowest);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Is there also a way to get the name of the `key` with the number?

Comment: Sure @Dawn17 - one second.

Comment: Is that what you want @Dawn17?

Comment: Yes, that's great! Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem @Dawn17, always glad to help.